# Tagging documents for doc2vec

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, word2vec, word-embeddings

I am working on resume parsing script. I am trying to tag documents sentences with TaggedDocument function, provided by gensim.

What I have managed for now is to divide every text into sentence, put into one flat array and give every sentence an i (its order, basically) tag.

```
tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(_d.lower()), tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(texts_flat)]
```

For the reason of possible improvement I want to tag every sentence not only with its order but with the name/order of text it is from. For that, I have made a list of lists, where every text is a list and every text contain list of sentences. i.e

```
texts = [text1 = [sent1, sent2, ...], text2, text3 ...]
```

1. How to iterate over this kind of document?
   I came up with smth like

   `tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(_d.lower()), tags=[str(i) + '.'+ str(j)]) for i, j, _d in enumerate(texts)]`

   but i get ValueError

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

2. Is it even going to do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to write a function that iterates over it for me:

```
class TaggedDocumentIterator(object):
def __init__(self, doc_list, labels_list):
    self.labels_list = labels_list
    self.doc_list = doc_list
def __iter__(self):
    for idx, doc in enumerate(self.doc_list):
        for idy in enumerate(doc):
            yield TaggedDocument(words=idy[1].split(), tags=[str(self.labels_list[idx]) + '.' + str(doc.index(idy[1]))])
```

`docLabels = list(range(len(texts)))
data = list(texts)
sentences = TaggedDocumentIterator(data, docLabels)`

Comment: out of curiosity (if you're still around), how did this model tagging system go?

Comment: @frei still working on this project. Still using this function :) This model was pretty good for tagging the resume into blocks, containing some specific info: education, experience, skills etc. Now I moved a bit further, and for each of these blocks I have a model for classification. So, for education block, there are University class, period of education class, specialization class etc.